# "cout" does not name a type error

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying pure virtual function. So I have written code accordingly.
But I ma not getting any problem because of that. I am getting "cout does not name a type" error in my code, even I have included proper header file and namespace as well.
Please give your suggestions for this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {
  virtual void foo();
};

void S::foo() {
  // body for the pure virtual function `S::foo`
 cout<<"I am S::foo()" <<endl;
}

struct D : S {
  cout <<"I am inside D::foo()" <<endl;
};

int main() {
  S *ptr;
  D d;
  ptr=&d;
  //ptr->foo();
  d.S::foo(); // another static call to `S::foo`
  cout <<"Inside main().." <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You tried to define a **struct** with direct code, but it looks like you wanted a **method** around the code:

```
struct D : S {
  cout <<"I am inside D::foo()" <<endl;
};
```

should probably be

```
struct D : S {
  virtual void foo() {
    cout <<"I am inside D::foo()" <<endl;
  }
};
```